# Pushing A Struct Instance Into An Struct Array Of A Different Struct Mapping

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design

How can I push a struct instance into a mapping which contains a distinct struct which contains a struct array of the attempted struct instance type?

Example:

```
contract NewBook {

    struct ChapterData {
        string chapterID;
        string title;
        uint pages;
    }

    struct BookData {
        string bookID;
        ChapterData[] chapters;
    }

    mapping(string => BookData) public books;

    //This is where the problem occurs, how do I add a struct instance 
    //into a struct containing an array of the struct that I'm trying to add?
    function addChapter(string memory _bookID, string memory _chapterID) public {
        books[_bookID].chapters.push(ChapterData[_chapterID]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract NewBook {

    struct ChapterData {
        // string chapterID;
        string title;
        uint pages;
    }

    struct BookData {
        // string bookID;
        ChapterData[] chapters;
    }

    mapping(bytes32 => BookData) books; // bookId => BookData

    //This is where the problem occurs, how do I add a struct instance 
    //into a struct containing an array of the struct that I'm trying to add?
    function addChapter(bytes32 _bookID, string memory title, uint pages) public {
        ChapterData memory c = ChapterData({
            title: title,
            pages: pages
        });
        books[_bookID].chapters.push(c);
    }

    function getBookChapter(bytes32 bookId, uint chapter) public view returns(string memory title, uint pages) {
        BookData storage b = books[bookId];
        ChapterData storage c = b.chapters[chapter];
        return(c.title, c.pages);
    }
}
```

This isn't the ideal or complete organization, but hopefully clears up the question raised.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you view the specific chapter data if you mind Rob?

Comment: I'll revise the answer.

Comment: thank you :D you're way more useful than my university!